# Jelurida Public License (jpl) and IGNIS ico

Tags: ardor, ignis, ico-initial-coin-offering

I've heard alot of hype from several sources about IGNIS coins receiving a share of new coins it is used to forge, but when I finally got round to reading the JPL it appears NXT is the coin that will receive a 10% share (proportional to holdings), but for coins created when the software is FORKED, not when a parent chain forges a child chain?

Could someone clarify what forking the software means it this context and it's implications?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a soft fork?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/30821/5406)

Comment: That answers partially for those who didn't know that dogecoin could be considered a fork. But the benefits of being a child chain in the context of Ardor is the root coin is secured with many nodes. Is forking therefore creating a new (unsecured) root? Or in contrast do you fork the software to create your business specific need which you then include as a child chain to be secured by Ardor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about IGNIS to answer this question myself. I added some tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you held NXT during the ignis snapshop on 2017 Dec, 28 you'd receive .5 ignis once the Ardor platform releases in 2018. As for the JPL license, supposedly you'd receive 10% of the coins being created with a new fork of NXT. Also child chains on Ardor are giving out airdrops if you hold ignis like bitswift. (https://www.jelurida.com/bitswift)

> Paul Busch also announced that he will be giving away 10% of all
>   Bitswift tokens to all holders of Ignis coins, relative to the amount
>   of Ignis coins they are allocated at the time of the Ardor Genesis
>   Snapshot. However, all funds for this 10% giveaway will come from
>   Paul’s own personal funds. Bitswift does not intend to compete with
>   Ignis as a child chain, but rather to complement the entire platform.
>   Additionally, further customized development will be explored that
>   will not only differentiate the two chains, but also provide the
>   needed customizations that Bitswift requires. Some features will also
>   be disabled due to business reasons as requested by Bitswift.