# What is the difference between 51% attack fork, hard fork and soft fork?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork, soft-fork

I am confused between the forking that can be created because of the 51% attack and the soft fork and hard fork.

Does forks because of 51% attack can also lead to new crypto currency creation?

Comment: I came across the link https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/bitcoin-fork-undergoes-51-attack-settlement-assurances-matter-2021-08-05 where bitcoin fork undergo 51% attack.

Comment: The Nasdaq article is about a 51% attack on BSV, not on Bitcoin (BTC). I personally would be careful not to assume that what happened to BSV could happen to BTC or that if it did happen, the results would be similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any forking that results from a 51% attack is a fork of the blockchain. It is a fork in the data, not in the rules.

The phrases "hard fork" and "soft fork" usually refer to a fork in the Bitcoin rules. So that is a fork due to software changes that implement either a change in the so-called consensus rules or a change in the network protocol.

So they are different in that way.

So far as I know, there has never been a successful 51% attack in Bitcoin, so I don't think we can say for certain what a long term outcome might look like. I guess that all blockchain forks are eventually resolved one way or another.

---

See [What is a soft fork? What is a hard fork? What are their differences?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/30817/13866)

Comment: Arguably, every softfork is technically indistinguishable from a 51% attack of the upgraded miners on the non-upgraded miners. The distinction between calling it an attack or a soft-fork change is social (but relevant!) - and depends on whether nodes (and ultimately the community) go along with the change (and help enforce it).